# Why doesn’t my timer wait for the time set? How to fix?

Tags: java, time, timer, sleep

I'm making this assignment where user chooses between "on time" and "countdown" check boxes, set time for delay, countdown or on time, new window opens and it changes colors. Countdown works fine, it waits for set time after which an app starts. The problem is with "on time" option, everything works fine until I press start button, it starts right away. It doesn't wait for time set.

```
{if (jCheckBox1.isSelected())
st=true;
set = jFormatted.getText();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  
   try 
       Date  date = sdf.parse(set);
       date.toString();
    catch (ParseException ex) 
       Logger.getLogger(TimerApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   
    sw = new SwingWorker() 
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception 
             
          Thread.sleep(s.getTime1());
            FrameBoja.Pocetak();
            while(st)
               
                FrameBoja.cf.getContentPane().setBackground(s.getColor());
                Thread.sleep(s.getSpeed());
                 FrameBoja.cf.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color (44,62,80)); 
                  Thread.sleep(s.getSpeed());  
            
            return null;
        
    
    sw.execute();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

### LocalTime from java.time

Use `LocalTime.parse(set)` for parsing the set time (you don’t need a formatter for this since your string is in ISO 8601 format, the default for `LocalTime`). A `LocalTime` is a time of day without a date. I think that this is what you need.

Use `LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Yellowknife"))` for obtaining the current time. Supply your desired time zone instead of America/Yellowknife.

Use `ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between` for calculating the difference in milliseconds between now and the set time. Basically this is the number of milliseconds to pass to `Thread.sleep`. However, if the number is negative, don’t sleep at all since the set time is already overdue (and `Thread.sleep` would throw an exception if you gave it a negative number).

### And use ScheduledExecutorService

One would usually prefer to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` that you get from `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool​` instead of calling `Thread.sleep` directly. You may try it. The way to calculate the delay would still be the same as above.

### Don’t use SimpleDateFormat and Date

I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome.

What went wrong in your code was probably: You are not supplying a date, only a time of day. `SimpleDateFormat` defaults to January 1, 1970. Since that time is long past (no matter the time of day you supplied), the loop started right away.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)